# Criar Tabela no SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Há possibilidade de criar uma tabela de `CAIXA` que, por exemplo, quando colocar o `CODIGO` do produto, puxe a `DESCRIÇÃO` automático, sendo que está na tabela de `PRODUTOS`??

Comment: Você quer evitar joins?

Comment: Você pode fazer joins

Comment: Dependendo do contexto você pode criar uma view para simplificar certas consultas, e claro vai precisar de joins na consutrução dela.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de alcançar isso é utilizando uma Coluna Computada com uma função, sendo que essa função vá realizar um `select` na tabela `Produtos`
Exemplo:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getDescricaoProduto(@produtoID int)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @retorno varchar(50)
    set @retorno =(Select Descricao from Produtos where ProdutoId = @produtoID)
    RETURN @retorno
END

ALTER TABLE dbo.Caixa ADD
    ProdutoDescricao AS dbo.getDescricaoProduto(ProdutoId)
GO
```

Vide resposta no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867047/sql-server-computed-column-select-from-another-table